# MySql (InnoDB)/Maria: Insert, ignore, lock and select?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to implement an end-user locking system e.g.,

```
 "CREATE TABLE foo (
  resource_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      user_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (resource_id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB $collate;" );
```

When a user checks out the resource, I want to attempt to insert a row for the resource and user. There may already be another user entry for the given resource in which case I want to select that user ID from the existing row while I still hold a lock. If there's no existing row, I want the insert to succeed and then select the same user ID out that I just inserted before releasing the lock.

Would something like this do what I'm hoping or is there a better way?

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT IGNORE INTO foo (resource_id, user_id) VALUES (4, 2)
SELECT user_id FROM foo WHERE resource_id = 4
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html:

> If a duplicate-key error occurs, a shared lock on the duplicate index record is set.

Given that, I think the INSERT IGNORE and then SELECT within the same transaction should work.